# Keycloak security for Spring base rest apis

Tags: rest, spring-boot, keycloak

I want to integrate keycloak security features to my spring boot based rest apis.
I am using KeyCloak 1.3.1 Final.
Now this is pure rest based api and am doing my testing through [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

I have got my rest api secured and when i try to access it do asks me for authorization, but am not able to execute my request. basically am locked out of my api.

I will quickly list out things that I have already done

1. Created a spring boot rest api and tested it. It works fine.
2. Modified my gradle for KeyCloak and configured it as per this [document](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#spring-boot-adapter)
3. Configured my keyCloak for the "bearer only" application
4. I tried to generate access token, but I was not able to. Therefore I created another Client in keycloak with "confidential" and used this client to generate the access token (both the clients were pointing to same application. Am not sure if this is correct)
5. With this access token, I am trying to make api call but am getting 401
   Again am using this [document](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/direct-access-grants.html).

I am new to both keycloak and spring.

---

So what I want to ask here is how can we generate the access token for testing a rest api in a scenario like one which is here.

Any useful resource on KeyCloak that can help me out here. As of now I dont have a clue as to where the problem is? Is it with my api or with how I have configured the KeyCloak. 
Also since I am new to spring and I just could not found a decent document on how to configure cloak for spring boot. If you can help with that as well.

---

Moving further on this I was informed on the KeyCloak mailing list that spring boot adapter only supports basic authentication, and so I decided to incorporate the spring security adapter itself.
I did that and when am running the application and providing creds am still not able to make it work. However something interesting is happening. I am being redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8090/sso/login
I double checked it and that is not the redirect url i have provided.
???
Any idea why?
(Once again am new to it and learning about spring and security on way through this project. So please bear with me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending quite a good amount of time and getting some help from keycloak user list here is how i got it to work.

1. Use Spring Security instead of spring boost security adapter (as I have already mentioned in the the edit, boot adapter is only for basic authentication)

There [documentation](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#spring-security-adapter) does a decent job of explaining out everything else refer to that.

I am still testing the whole thing and will document it out for future references.

Comment: Anunay, could you please describe how you managed to fix redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8090/sso/login and obtain a correct token?

Comment: So there are few things that we need to be careful of, first we are using bearer only application, To generate the token we talk to one of the confidential app and get the access token (make sure the redirect url for this is sett correctly). If you have the access token you shhould be able to work your way through. Can you tell me where you facing the problem and probably I can contribute more

Comment: Its long time due, but here is sample that I wrote for a small [demo](https://github.com/XMansion/Kingcross)